# How to display a user's foursquare name and photo in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, foursquare

Rails newbie, so any help appreciated.

I've got Foursquare authorization working after following this excellent Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

However, now I want to display the users name and photo on the user/show page.

How do I do this?

Comment: can you show some code, even if conceptual, of where you are?  Will help in getting you more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the User detail -
 "Returns profile information for a given user ID".

The docs are here: https://developer.foursquare.com/, and the documentation for the users endpoint is here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/users.

The JSON that's returned contains a photo field (described here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user).

I find that the easiest way to play with and understand our API is this explore tool:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=users/self

Comment: Thanks, guys - will have a look through the documentation.